# Como gravar dados no firebase pelo Ionic sem apagar o que já está gravado?

Tags: ionic, firebase

Meu metodo Create está assim

```
create(user: User, uuid: string): Promise<void> {
return this.db.object(`/users/${uuid}`)
  .set(user)
  .catch(this.handlePromiseError);
}
```

E a minha classe User está assim

```
export class User {

public $key: string;

constructor(
    public name: string,
    public username: string,
    public email: string,
    public photo: string
) {}

}
```

Só que quando eu vou gravar no firebase, o id fica indefinido e quando gravo outro dado ele se sobrepõe ao primeiro e apaga.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?hl=pt-br Use as transações. Isso deve resolver o seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente fazer um `push()`:

```
create(user: User): Promise<void> {
return this.db.object(`/users`)
  .push(user)
  .catch(this.handlePromiseError);
}
```

Comment: O push está dando erro

Comment: Está dizendo que o push não existe no AngularFireObject